# Fuse blown indicator circuits compilation

Tags: output, fuses, indicator

I have been working in a compilation of circuits to use that basically show to the user that a fuse has blown up, this is particulary useful in the bench, needless to say I haven’t tested all of them yet (transistor and SCR), and i want to leave them here to receive feedback about how to improve them or fix any mistakes you can find, if anyone can come up with any other designs in order to add them to the compilation, what they have to do is easy

1. Make a led turn on, when the fuse has blown
2. Work for positive and negative voltages

Up to now, the best design i have tested is the mosfet one that, makes the led turn on with or without a load connected this is helpfull since saves time and works for both possitive and neg voltages with some changes

[image]

Comment: Your "SCR indicator" actually doesn't contain fuse, so what do yo want to indicate then? Your "MOSFET indicators" do not make sense at all. You have two pins with name "OUT", and fuse is connected from one "OUT" pin do mosfet gate. Which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using this very often.
With little modification, you can adapt to other DC votages or polarities.
With good fuse only green led lights. When fuse is blown only red LED light up.

[image]

Also you can use a dual colour LED with common cathode instead of two single.